# If I copy a clone of a double-faced card, can the copy transform?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards, mtg-tokens

From the rule change in MOM tokens can now transform. A clone of a double-faced card however cannot transform since it isn't doubled-faced.

What happens then if I copy the clone? Will the token copy be able to transform or not?

Let's say I have [Spark Double](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spark%20Double) enter as a copy of [Arcee, Sharpshooter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcee%2C%20Sharpshooter), and I then copy my Spark Double with [Rite of Replication](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rite%20of%20Replication). Will the token copies of Spark Double be able to transform, and if so, will the resulting [Arcee, Acrobatic Coupe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcee%2C%20Acrobatic%20Coupe) be legendary or not?

Comment: The answer to this seems to hinge completely on what the definition of "transforming permanent" is, and I cannot find any such definition in the comprehensive rules. It is clear that the Spark Double is not a double-faced card, but it is completely unclear whether it is a "transforming permanent" or not.

Comment: The rules talk about "transforming tokens and permanents represented by transforming double-faced cards" as a category. I can't see another reasonable interpretation of "transforming permanent".

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes, shortly after I wrote that comment I came to the same conclusion, that it was the only reasonable interpretation. Still would be nice if the comprehensive rules either defined the term directly, or consistently used "transforming tokens and permanents represented by transforming double-faced cards" in 707.8a.

Comment: I had originally been thinking that a reasonable definition/interpretation of "transforming permanent" was "a permanent that has a transform ability".

Comment: There aren't really "transform abilities". There are effects that cause a permanent to transform, and effects that cause a permanent to enter the battlefield transformed. Battles can be cast transformed due to a rule, not an ability, and many TDFCs have an ability that allows them to transform or enter transformed only on the front face.

Comment: This is relevant because [Lazotep Convert](https://scryfall.com/card/mom/231/invasion-of-amonkhet-lazotep-convert), for example, is a transforming double-faced card with a Clone-like effect.

Comment: You *may* have Spark Double enter the battlefield as a copy of another card, but if you would rather play a 0/0 creature with no abilities that's okay too. Gotta love it. (Yeah, I know, it's to prevent you from getting stuck if you're forced to play Spark Double but there's nothing eligible for it to copy.)

Comment: Right, and if Spark Double is on the battlefield not copying anything (some other effect must be giving it extra toughness to survive), then when you copy it with Rite of Replication, the token copies will have its copy ability, so you will chose what each one copies as it enters the battlefield.

Comment: The more likely scenario for not copying anything with Spark Double is that you cast it deliberately, and the only copyable permanents are removed in response. The spell still resolves, but the only available choice is to have it copy nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the token copy will not be a transforming token, because the object it is copying is not a transforming double-faced card or a transforming token.

> 707.8a If an effect creates a token that is a **copy of a transforming permanent** or a transforming double-faced card not on the battlefield, the resulting token is a transforming token that has both a front face and a back face. The characteristics of each face are determined by the copiable values of the same face of the permanent it is a copy of, as modified by any other copy effects that apply to that permanent. If the token is a copy of a transforming permanent with its back face up, the token enters the battlefield with its back face up. This rule does not apply to tokens that are created with their own set of characteristics and enter the battlefield as a copy of a transforming permanent due to a replacement effect.

The rules do not seem to specifically define "transforming permanent". However, everywhere else that "transforming" is talked about refers to "transforming double-faced card or transforming token". So it is a safe assumption that a "transforming permanent" must be either a transforming double-faced card or transforming token, which Spark Double is not. If you used Rite of Replication on Arcee instead, then the tokens would be transforming.